# Regular expression to not allow spaces anywhere in the email

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

I am trying to validate the email address using a regular expression such that it throws an error if white spaces are added anywhere in the email. The current regex I am using is this:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="username" ng-     model="username" id="email" placeholder="Email" ng-pattern='/^(([^<>()\    [\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/' required />
<span ng-show="login.username.$error.pattern">This email format is invalid!     </span>
```

The problem is it allows me to add white spaces in the end. How can I modify it so that if I add a whitespace in the end the error message is fired?

Comment: Most of the cases I have seen we trim email/similar values before we use them from user forms.

Comment: For some reason I need to allow the user to submit only when the email field does not contain any spaces. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have best solution in regular expression, but If I am in such situation, I would try compare actual email and trimmed email. if both are same then invoke regular expression validation. else show error to user.

Comment: There isn't really a Regular Expression that will cover all email addresses as they can be pretty much anything, the best thing would be to just trim the value in the form submit function

Answer (score 3):

The newest release of angularJs (1.5.7) includes some email address validation improvements.

You can check the commit [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/f423dc6b51a9b4a09728a287a2cabda7d45f192e).

Line 28 corresponds to the committed regex:

```
var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^(?=.{1,254}$)(?=.{1,64}@)[-!#$%&'*+\/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+(\.[-!#$%&'*+\/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?(\.[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?)*$/;
```

Below the directive's code you have the tests to validate the regex. It does check for white spaces.